# How to display names of objects in viewport

Tags: workflow, 3d-view

Is there anyway to display the names of objects in a scene, all at once like the option we have for bones? Yes,we can do it individually..but if there are many objects its better to have common control.
I am working with a mechanical assembly,its very difficult to keep track of objects.
Any hidden option or  add-on information would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Select all objects by hiting <kbd>A</kbd>. Then in the
*Properties* areas *Object* tabs *Display*
group check the checkbox *Name* for name display.
Then right click the checkbox and select the option
*Copy To Selected*. Works on almost all options.

Edit: In current versions, using alt-click on
properties applies them for every selected object.

Comment: Woah awesome. I've still been changing things and then trying to figure out which ctrl-c category will replacate them ("draw options" for this one)

Comment: "using alt-click on properties applies them for every selected object." Sweet! :-D I've been using Blender a while now and this is news to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The UI has been updated. As of version 2.82, still use `A` to select all, then *Properties panel > Object > Viewport Display > Name*, use **ctrl-alt-click** to toggle the setting for all selected objects.